# Count certain values in a Column by filtering another Column "Date"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I Have

| Process | Assists | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23d34 | 0,0 | 13.10.2020 |
| 23d4t | 1 | 14.10.2020 |
| 56z45 | 3 | 13.10.2020 |
| 2387e | 0,0 | 17.10.2020 |
| 56z45 | 0,0,0 | 14.10.2020 |
| 3249u | 0,0 | 15.10.2020 |
| 3209r | 0,0 | 27.10.2020 |
| n98b3 | 1,4 | 14.10.2020 |

I want to count the number of "0,0" in the Row "Assists" from 13.10.2020 till 20.10.2020.
How do I do that?
Using

```
count = df.assisted_count[df.assisted_count.apply(lambda x : str(x).strip() == "0,0")].size
```

gives me the total number of 0,0, but I need it for certain time periods.
Hope someone can help me?

Thanks a lot =)

Answer (score 0):

Let's try converting [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to make filtering by date easier. Then creating a Boolean series that matches dates [between](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) the start and end range, and also matches target string `'0,0'` . If just the count of matches is needed can use [sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html) instead of filtering the DataFrame:

```
# Make Date column datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d.%m.%Y')
# Filter Date between Start and End
date_m = df['Date'].between('2020-10-13', '2020-10-20')
# Check Where 'Assists' is '0,0'
zz_m = df['Assists'].str.strip().eq('0,0')
# Add up all the places where both conditions are true
count = (date_m & zz_m).sum()
```

count = 3.

`df`:

```
  Process Assists       Date
0   23d34     0,0 2020-10-13  # Date column is now datetime
1   23d4t       1 2020-10-14
2   56z45       3 2020-10-13
3   2387e     0,0 2020-10-17
4   56z45   0,0,0 2020-10-14
5   3249u     0,0 2020-10-15
6   3209r     0,0 2020-10-27
7   n98b3     1,4 2020-10-14
```

---

Can also use a separate `Series` rather than updating the Date column to be datetime:

```
# Make separate series from Date column
s = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d.%m.%Y')
date_m = s.between('2020-10-13', '2020-10-20')
zz_m = df['Assists'].str.strip().eq('0,0')
count = (date_m & zz_m).sum()
```

count = 3.

`df`:

```
  Process Assists        Date
0   23d34     0,0  13.10.2020  # Date col has not been modified
1   23d4t       1  14.10.2020
2   56z45       3  13.10.2020
3   2387e     0,0  17.10.2020
4   56z45   0,0,0  14.10.2020
5   3249u     0,0  15.10.2020
6   3209r     0,0  27.10.2020
7   n98b3     1,4  14.10.2020
```